# Custom Links/Buttons in SharePoint Online 2010 Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I'm new to SharePoint and am looking to add some custom links or buttons to the ribbon (only want these to show on the ribbon when the advanced ribbon menu controls are not showing, if that makes sense).  I'm on SharePoint Online (2010 edition, but will convert to 2013 shortly).

Here's a screenshot of where I'm looking to add links or buttons.

[image: Right side of closed ribbon area]

I think the code section in the v4.master that controls this area is this section but I'm having problems getting my links to show up in the correct area.

```
<div class="s4-trc-container-menu">
     <div>
        <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
        </wssuc:Welcome>
        <wssuc:MUISelector ID="IdMuiSelector" runat="server"/>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Any suggestions?  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using v4.master as your master page (default), there is a control with an ID of "RibbonTabRowRight" that surrounds the code snippet you have posted.

Any links and buttons that you want to add should go within this control, and before the Welcome Menu (the snippet you have posted).  Whether you use a simple anchor tag or a more complex control depends on your requirements.

Example:

```
<SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                runat="server"
                Location="TabRowRight"
                ID="RibbonTabRowRight"
                CssClass="s4-trc-container s4-notdlg">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ID="GlobalDelegate0" ControlId="GlobalSiteLink0" />
     <a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="display:none"></a><a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="display:none"></a>
     <div class="s4-trc-container-menu">
         <a href="EXAMPLE.ASPX" />MY EXAMPLE</a>
         <div>
            <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
            </wssuc:Welcome>
            <wssuc:MUISelector ID="IdMuiSelector" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink2" ID="GlobalDelegate2" Scope="Farm" runat="server" />
    <span>
        <span class="s4-devdashboard">
            <Sharepoint:DeveloperDashboardLauncher
                ID="DeveloperDashboardLauncher"
                NavigateUrl="javascript:ToggleDeveloperDashboard()"
                runat="server"
                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                Text="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_launchdevdashalt_text%>"
                OffsetX=0
                OffsetY=222
                Height=16
                Width=16 />
        </span>
    </span>
            </SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
```

Comment: thanks - that is definitely the right spot, but I can't get the link to move down and to the left of the Welcome Menu.  Right now it's hovering above and slightly to the left of the Welcome Menu.  I've put in a div and some other simple HTML to make it move, but that is being ignored. Can I add a new CSS class directly to the default v4.master or do you have any other suggestions to get it moved to the right place?  Thanks!

Comment: Same thing here.  Did you ever figure out what to do?